# How to overlay text onto a series of several images

Tags: android

I have a project (similar to a calendar) where appointments are blocked and appear as a box 1 pixel per minute (in a grid view each box is one pixel tall) and then I want to overlay text onto a box that might span several minutes or several rows. Is there a good way to do this or should we take another approach that might work better?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the use of a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) might help you. Also take a look at [that example](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/), notice that the TextView is on top on the ImageView.